# How to delete the last dynamically generated div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my html div #field is generated dynamically by button click.
While clicking it has to delete the last div field.

html

```
<div class="col-12" id="buildyourform" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
<div class="fieldwrapper input-group input-group-sm mb-3 overflow-auto" id="field1">
<input type="number" class="fieldname col-6 form-control" id="af1">
<input type="number" class="fieldtype col-4 form-control" id="sp1">1</div>
<div class="fieldwrapper input-group input-group-sm mb-3 overflow-auto" id="field2">
<input type="number" class="fieldname col-6 form-control" id="af2">
<input type="number" class="fieldtype col-4 form-control" id="sp2">2</div>
<div class="fieldwrapper input-group input-group-sm mb-3 overflow-auto" id="field3">
<input type="number" class="fieldname col-6 form-control" id="af3">
<input type="number" class="fieldtype col-4 form-control" id="sp3">3</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#addairdata').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
    var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
    // console.log(intId);
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper input-group input-group-sm mb-3 overflow-auto\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
    var fName = $("<input type=\"number\" class=\"fieldname col-6 form-control\" id=\"af" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fType = $("<input type=\"number\" class=\"fieldtype col-4 form-control\" id=\"sp" + intId + "\" />");

    // var fType = $("<select class=\"fieldtype\"><option value=\"checkbox\">Checked</option><option value=\"textbox\">Text</option><option value=\"textarea\">Paragraph</option></select>");
    // var removeButton = $("<button type=\"button\" class=\"col-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right\" disabled>"+intId+"</button>");
    // removeButton.click(function() {
    //     $(this).parent().remove();
    // });
    // console.log(intId);

    console.log(intId);


    var removeButton = $(".remove")

    removeButton.click(function() {

        console.log(intId-intId);
        // $("#buildyourform div:last-child").remove()
        // $("#field"+intId).remove();   
        // $("#field"+intId).remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fType);
    fieldWrapper.append(intId);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);

})
```

when ever the div is generated multiple time on remove button click it has to remove the last div and after that adding new div should have the consiscutive div id of last div at present

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Comment: Where is remove button!?

Comment: if you find answer good please accept or put comment

Comment: Yes Found the answer just need to move the remove button click event out of the add button event

Answer (score 0):

*Create A stack or array of string keep id of dynamic Element, write a method to deleted recent element use stack or array which hold ids of dynamic element to fetch id of recently added element  , then onclick of remove elelment by id like this*

```
function removeElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```